# AWS sdk ruby - get instance type specs

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to get the machine specs from the instance type?

```
get_spec("t1.small") => {CPU:64, RAM:8 ....HVM:true}
```

is there such kind of method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Amazon EC2 API does not expose these stats programmatically. For quick reference I tend to use: http://www.ec2instances.info/

They have a static JSON file you can fetch programmatically: 
http://www.ec2instances.info/instances.json

Comment: Thanks thats helps, Do you know what is the key there that indicates on the ephemeral storage? is that storage.devices?

Comment: I think so. I looked up t2.micro in the JSON document, which is EBS only. It had a null value for storage.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no this type of machine specs you can get directly from aws ruby SDK.

But you can develop this function by yourself to refer the url [Amazon EC2 Instances types](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/). Build an input yaml file with full informations, and search key word `t1.small` .

```
instance:
   t2.small:
       cpu: 1
       mem: 2
   t2.micro:
       cpu: 1
       mem: 1
```

with the ruby code, you can use the gem of `yaml`

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'yaml'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> config=YAML::load_file('instances.yaml')
=> {"instance"=>{"t2.small"=>{"cpu"=>1, "mem"=>2}, "t2.micro"=>{"cpu"=>1, "mem"=>1}}}
irb(main):003:0> config['instance']['t2.small']
=> {"cpu"=>1, "mem"=>2}
```